# PAYPAL IPN & PDT fail

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am working on a ordering system, where the payment is taken using PayPal.

Currently have issues with IPN.

I have used the sample IPN code provided via this link below:

```
https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php
```

However every time I test IPN via IPN Simulator it shows below error:

```
IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information.
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people have suggested that the IPN Simulator is broken.